# How to reverse a linked list implementation of a queue

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, reverse, function-definition

I'm trying to create a recursive function that reverses a linked list implementation of a queue using the enqueue and dequeue functions. I tried doing this:

```
void reverse(queue *q, node *node)  //this first node would be passed like: reverse(&queue, queue->first);
{
        if(node->next == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        reverse(q, node->next);
        int tmp;
        q->head = node;
        tmp = dequeue(q);
        enqueue(q, tmp);
}
    
    void enqueue(queue *q, int data)
{
        node *node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        node->data = data;
        node->next = NULL;
    
        if (q->tail != NULL)
            q->tail->next = node;

        q->tail = node;

        if (q->head == NULL)
            q->head = node;
    
        q->tail = node;
}
    
    int dequeue(queue *q)
{
        if (!empty(q)){
            node *tmp = q->head;
            int result = tmp->data;
            q->head = tmp->next;
            if (q->head == NULL)
                q->tail = NULL;
            free(tmp);
            return result;
        }
 }
```

It was actually making sense in my head but it just prints the 2 first numbers.

How can we code a recursive function to reverse a linked queue using enqueue and dequeue functions?

Comment: You should dequeue as you go deeper in the recursion. Stop the recursion when the queue is empty. Then enqueue as you climb up the recursion.

Comment: And the function signature should be `void reverse(queue *q)`. Don't be messing with the internals of the queue. You only need `enqueue`, `dequeue`, and `empty` to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a problem in this line:

```
    node *node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

As you shadow the *type* `node` by the *pointer* with the same name, the argument given to `sizeof` is wrong. Use a different variable name in that function.

Also, in C it is considered better not to cast what `malloc` returns:

```
    node *curnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    // ...use curnode below ...
```

#### The reverse function

The problem is with this line:

```
q->head = node;
```

As you have just reversed the queue that starts at `node->next`, `node->next` will now be the **tail** of the queue, so when you do the above assignment, you limit the queue to two elements, and lose the reference to the other nodes.

As a solution, don't use a second function argument, nor `next` references. Just dequeue - recurse - and enqueue again:

```
void reverse(queue *q)
{
    if (empty(q))
        return;
    int tmp = dequeue(q);
    reverse(q);
    enqueue(q, tmp);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! It's working perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

For starters your approach is inefficient because the function frees and allocates all nodes anew.

And it has a bug.

Consider  a queue that contains three nodes with values 1, 2, 3.

After the second and third recursive calls of the function you have the queue like

```
3, 2
```

Now due to the statement

```
q->head = node;
```

you have

```
1, 2
```

And after these calls

```
    tmp = dequeue(q);
    enqueue(q, tmp);
```

you have

```
2, 1
```

That is the node with the value 3 is lost.

Moreover the function can invoke undefined behavior called for an empty queue.

And the function should have only one parameter: the pointer to the queue.

The function can be defined simpler without redundant dynamic reallocations of nodes of the queue. For example

```
void reverse( queue *q )
{
    if (q->head != NULL && q->head->next != NULL)
    {
        node *current = q->head;
        q->head = q->head->next;
        reverse( q );
        q->tail->next = current;
        current->next = NULL;
        q->tail = current;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that there is a typo

```
    node *node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

the name of the variable node in this declaration hides the typedef name node of the declared structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion to reverse the list will result in a stack overflow error for an extremely long list.

You can reverse the list without recursion and without allocating any extra memory by just traversing the list and reversing the `next` member of each node to point to the previous element.

```
void reverse(queue* queue) {
    node* head = queue->head;
    node* tail = queue->tail;
    node* prev = queue->head;
    node* current = queue->head ? queue->head->next : NULL;
    node* next = current ? current->next : NULL;

    while (current) {
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        next = current ? current->next : NULL;
    }

    // fix up the head and tail of the list
    queue->head = tail;
    queue->tail = head;
    if (queue->tail) {
        queue->tail->next = NULL;
    }
}
```